# Plants suitable/safe for a hamster?

Tags: diet, safety, hamsters, plants, cage

I am trying to create a 'natural' looking hamster cage. I want to create as much enrichment as I can by using rocks, moss, wood, leaves, sand, dirt and other elements that would be natural to a (dwarf) hamster.

I've seen cages with plants in them but I'm not too familiar with plant species so I have no idea what would be safe for a hamster if he decides to eat it.

A lot of herbs would be safe but I know my hamster dislikes the smell of some herbs (mint and basil) so I don't want to annoy him with that constant smell in his cage. The plant does not need to be tasty/likeable for him but I'm fine if it is, I don't mind replacing it from time to time.

Next to that it will not be in constant direct sunlight as I do not want to expose the hamster to constant direct sunlight. There is natural light in the room and cage however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do know very little about hamsters but i know dandelions and cat grass/wheat grass is safe for hamsters.

I found this information on the net http://www.petwebsite.com/hamsters/hamster_plants_flowers.asp

> Alyssum
>
> Asters
>
> Bramble leaves
>
> Blackberry leaves
>
> Burnet
>
> Chickweed
>
> Clover
>
> Coltsfoot
>
> Cornflowers
>
> Cow Parsley
>
> Crosswort
>
> Dandelion leaves and flower
>
> Dock
>
> Groundsel
>
> Hawthorn leaves
>
> Hedge Parsley
>
> Knot Grass
>
> Mallow
>
> Marigolds
>
> Michaelmas Daisies
>
> Nasturtiums
>
> Nipplewort
>
> Phlox
>
> Plaintain
>
> Roses (i am not sure this is safe but it is mentioned as safe on the
>   website)
>
> Salvias
>
> Shepherds Purse
>
> Sow Thistle
>
> Sweetpeas
>
> Trefoil
>
> Vetch
>
> Wallflowers
>
> Watercress
>
> Young grass

Read more at http://www.petwebsite.com/hamsters/hamster_plants_flowers.asp#FU5RGt5wzDlMMJmj.99

These are safe plants but in the linked page there are a list of dangerous plants too.